# Set open if its complement is closed

Tags: general-topology

I'm working on a problem where my entire set is $[0,1]$ and I'm trying to argue that $[0,1)^c = \{1\}$ is open since the singleton is closed with the usual topology of $\Bbb R$, but it seems that the statement

> Set $A$ is open iff its complement is closed

is not true in general? Is this dependent on the "parent" set where $A$ resides? So for example $A \subset X$, then I would need to know something about $X$?

Comment: that statement is always true, and in many settings it is true just by definition of what a closed set is.

Comment: @Yorch Weird, I cannot find any mention about this even on the wikipedia page of open sets. I assume this would be something of an importance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_set

Comment: @Yorch This seems to only talk about the closedness of a set, but not the converse?

Comment: It's giving the definition of a closed set, so it's an if and only if condition.

Comment: A closed set is usually defined to be the complement of an open one. What definition of closed are you using?

Comment: In any case, it should be very easy to show directly  that every point of $[0,1)$ has an open neighborhood in that set.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to show $[0,1)$ is closed because $\{1\}$ is open. That's exactly backwards; neither statement is true. In fact $[0,1)$ is open because $\{1\}$ is closed...

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing yourself because $[0, 1)$ is not open in $\mathbb{R},$ but it **is** open in the subspace topology on $[0, 1].$ So, $\{1\}$ is closed in $[0, 1]$ because it's complement $[0, 1)$ is open.

Similarly, in $\mathbb{R},$ the set $[0, 1]$ is not open. But in the topology of $[0, 1],$ it *is* an open set, since in any topological space the entire space has to be an open subset.